# $x^3 - 3x - 1$ irreducible in $\mathbb Z[x]$ by Gauss Lemma

Tags: abstract-algebra, logic, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials

In Dummit & Foote, they claim this can be shown to be irreducible by Gauss Lemma and applying it to show it has no rational root.

> [image]

But this doesn't make sense to me since Gauss Lemma says:

Let $F$ be a field of fraction for UFD $R$, then if $p(x) \in F[x]$ is reducible, then $p(x) \in R[x]$ is reducible. Contrapositive say $p(x) \in R[x]$ irreducible, then $p(x) \in F[x]$ irreducible.

So they implies that $P \to Q$ is equivalent to $\sim P \to \sim Q$?

Comment: Some authors include both directions in the statement of Gauss' Lemma, so end up invoking a powerful theorem even when using only the trivial direction. Though they don't state it bidirectionally in the text, I wouldn't be surprised if they thought of it that way when composing the example. The same thing happens with many other common theorems stated bidirectionally, e.g. some authors invoke Bezout's GCD Theorem to deduce the trivial inference that $\,ax+bx=c\,$ is unsolvable if $\,\gcd(a,b)\nmid c.\ $

Comment: This is only a wrong quotation: replace Gauss' Lemma by its corollary (that is, Corollary 6 in the book).

Comment: @user26857 Which is one example of a bidirectional form of GL that I referred to above - so is an instance of said problem.

Comment: note the roots are $-2 \cos \frac{2 \pi}{9} , \; \; -2 \cos \frac{4 \pi}{9} , \; \; -2 \cos \frac{8 \pi}{9} , \; \; $ which may help give some feel of irrationality

Answer (score 2):

It's almost trivial that irreducible over $\Bbb Q$ implies irreducible over $\Bbb Z$ (as long as the polynomial is monic). That's not what Gauss' lemma says.

The way I read the D&F quote, you definitely don't need Gauss' lemma for this. You just need its converse, which is the above mentioned triviality, along with propositions 10 and 11 (which presumably is the rational root theorem).

Comment: I will edit. But it is on page 308.

Comment: Prop 10 is just about degree > 2,3 is reducible iff it has a root (a linear factor).

Comment: @Hawk Beware that the trivial direction only works for polys that are *primitive* (e.g. here monic)  since e.g. $\,2x\,$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Q[x]$ but it is a product of primes in $\,\Bbb Z[x]\ $

Comment: @BillDubuque You're right. In addition, $2x+1$ shows that you can have rational roots which aren't integer. I clarified in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

It seems to me that you don’t need Gauss Lemma. Indeed you want to prove that $x^3-3x-1=0$ is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$.

Here another approach: Consider the polynomial 
$$x^3-3x-1=0$$ and take the reduction modulo $2$. It becomes $$x^3+x+1=0.$$ Since it has not solution in $\Bbb Z_2$, no solution exists in $\Bbb Z$. Hence the original polynomial is irreducible in $\Bbb Z[x]$

Comment: Well I know that, but I want to know what the heck did he mean.